# Websocket server performance comparison

Tags: performance, frameworks, websocket, scalability

Are there any reliable performance test results/benchmarks/comparisons for websocket server frameworks?

I was googlin to and fro without any significant results. Going by various of Google's instant search suggestions, it seems to be a really hot topic, but the search results are far from satisfying. So a good answer is highly appreciated!

#### Background

I need to implement websockets for an application that has to be able to scale well, and would therefore like to knoow if there are any big performance differences amongst the available frameworks. I do not really care (too much) about the specific programming language, as stated above performance as well as scalability (+ obviously stability) are the important factors.

#### What I found so far

- A more or less functional check with some time measurements by [the autobahn testsuite](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/reports/servers/index.html), comparing their implementation (with CPy, pypy, wsaccel) against 4 others (Jetty, Websocket++, cowboy, ws)
- A websockets byproduct of the HTTP comparison between [MochiWeb and cowboy](http://idorobots.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/erlang-mochiweb-cowboy/)

So it is not much, but maybe at least these help someone also looking for an answer.

*Aside*: If you think this question is not good as is, please consider editing rather than close-voting it, (I found out that I am not a good OP ^^) I would really appreciate it, and there really is a great demand for a good answer to this (kind of) question.

Comment: I have plans to do a test with the most known .NET frameworks, but it will have to wait a couple of weeks. I have one about WebSocketListener (that I developed): https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-performance-tests

Comment: @vtortola: Thx in advance, and for the additional test.

Comment: One year ago, we published a benchmark comparing performance of Lightstreamer and Socket.IO: http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/05/benchmarking-socketio-vs-lightstreamer.html [Full disclosure: I work for Lightstreamer - http://www.lightstreamer.com ]